# CertMgr Succeeded but cannot find in Manage Computer Certificates

Tags: certificate

I have a root certificate for self signed localhost certificate and need to be installed in localmachine Trusted Root Certificate Authorities. I have the following command to do the work

`certmgr.exe -add -all -c rootCert.cer -s -r localmachine trustedrootcertificationauthorities`

In command line, it shows `CertMgr Succeeded`, but I cannot find the certificate.

Then I double Click the root certificate and use Certificate Import Wizard. After certificate is imported, I can see the certificate in Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.

Can anyone please help on it? I want to get the certmgr.exe working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. The command should be

```
certmgr.exe -add -all -c rootCert.cer -s -r localmachine root
```